# find the highest score from a list in case more than 1 person have the highest score?

Tags: python, list, max

I have homework and this is the problem. I am just new to python so I am trying my best but so far I still do not meet the requirements. Please help me!

The first program will ask the user to enter the name and score of each participant
and then save the data in a file named result.txt. The second program will read data from the result.txt file created in the first program and display all of the contents in a good format and also the number of participants and the name(s) and the score of all people with the highest score. You need to consider the case that more than 1 person has the highest score.

The first part I have it work, but not properly. My teacher says I should use try and except to make sure the input is from 0 and 300. The score should not be negative. But my try-except is not executed the input that is negative.
This is my first part:

```
print('-----Program for Bowling Tournament-----')

# set the value for the n amount of student

n=int(input('Enter the number of students participating in the competition: '))

i=1 # Set the value for i as first loop

with open('result.txt','w') as f:
    
    while i<=n: # use a while loop to count the number of student input'
        # Input the first student info mation 
        student=int(input('For students numbers: '))

        # Input the name of the student

        name=input('Enter name of the student: ')

        # Input the score of the student
        
        score = int(input(f'Please enter a bowling score of student: '))

        # set the requirements of the score to use try-except
        
        try:
        # because the highest score in a bowling game is 300 and the score must be positive integers
        
            if not (0 <= score <= 300):
                
                raise ValueError(f'{score} is not between 0 and 300')
            # start except value
        
        except ValueError as e: # try using the loop 
            print(f'Error: {e}. Please Try again.')
        # keep the loop going by plus one more in n
        i +=1
        # write the input into the file result.txt
        
        f.write(name + " " + str(score)+'\n')
        
# print the file text insde 
f.close()

with open('result.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
f.close()
```

The second part I can only print one highest score but not all highest score. Some times it print the lower value not the highest value

This is a code:

```
# program 2 : Score highest


with open('result.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()


highest_score = 1

highest_score_name = {''}

 

for line in file_content:

    line = line.strip()

    # Check whether the line is empty

    if line == '':

        continue



    if int(score) > highest_score: 
        highest_score = int(score)

        highest_score_name.update(name)
 

print('the name and score of the record with highest score:')

print('Name:', highest_score_name)

print('Score:', highest_score)


 

f.close()
```